# "As I had intended to" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

My wife and I are debating the correct ending of a sentence that ends with, "... I did not return to school as I had intended" in a (college level) school paper that is being written.

One of us thinks the sentence should end, "..as I had intended to," the other is violently opposed to ending the sentence with the word "to."

What says the community?

Comment: Nevo, welcome. You can search on this site for several question and many answers about the advice not to end a sentence with a preposition. As to whether the clause is incorrect, in general, with the last *to*, that is also open to discussion. It is certainly not wrong. In fact, the question I have marked that this one is a duplicate of discusses both issues, although in the context of a different verb phrase.

Comment: No, the "to" is definitely not needed, and I would argue is incorrect. If I say "I intend to return to school", the "to" is part of the infinitive verb "return". It is not part of the verb "intend". However, since "intend" is frequently followed by an infinitive, it is assumed by some people that "intend" always takes "to". However when you restructure the sentence so that the infinitive is not employed, you do not need, and it is wrong to use "to". As a native speaker, who is not a linguist by profession, that is my take on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more one of register than grammar.

The partial ellipsis of an infinitive, leaving only the infinitive marker *to*, a particular form of [verb phrase ellipsis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase_ellipsis), is common in informal spoken English:

> I couldn't say what I wanted to [*say*].
>   Why did you destroy the painting? The artist asked me to [*destroy the painting*].
>   Why did she sell her car? She had to [*sell her car*].

In more formal academic writing, such a construction would be out of place, so a full ellipsis of the dependent infinitive is required.

> He did not return as he intended.